# aiohttp session closed without exiting the context manager

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a pretty complicated API with custom parameters and headers so I created a class to wrap around it. Here's a contrived example:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

# The wrapper class around my API
class MyAPI:
    def __init__(self, base_url: str):
        self.base_url = base_url

    async def send(self, session, method, url) -> aiohttp.ClientResponse:
        request_method = getattr(session, method.lower())
        full_url = f"{self.base_url}/{url}"

        async with request_method(full_url) as response:
            return response

async def main():
    api = MyAPI("https://httpbin.org")

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await api.send(session, "GET", "/uuid")
        print(response.status)       # 200 OK
        print(await response.text()) # Exception: Connection closed

asyncio.run(main())
```

Why is my session closed? I didn't exit the context manager of `session`.

If I ignore the wrapper class, everything works as expected:

```py
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://httpbin.org/uuid") as response:
            print(await response.text())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call response.text() once you have left the `request_method(full_url)` context.

If you write:

```
        async with request_method(full_url) as response:
            text = await response.text()
            return response.status, text
```

then the `send()` method returns without error.

Comment: I see. Thank you!